# Web Deployment Projects, Team Suite 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

I get the following  when I build locally

```
 Granting IIS read access to the folder 'C:\Projects\YourClubMatters\Trunk\YCM\WebSite_deploy\Release'.
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\WebDeployment\v9.0\Microsoft.WebDeployment.targets(676,5): error : Some or all identity references could not be translated.
Warning: Unable to grant IIS access to folder 'C:\Projects\YourClubMatters\Trunk\YCM\WebSite_deploy\Release'.
```

I get this error when building locally or on the team foundation server.

Not exactly sure how to solve it, have the iis app pool and web site running as the tfs user so it doesn't have any problem viewing the website but the error is really irritating as its always telling me my build is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem:
http://lacy.ie/web-deployment-project-iis-deploy-error-on-team-foundation-server/

Answer (score 0):

Run an audit on the folder in question and find out the failed access attempt. that will tell you which account is having the problem. You can then grant access rights to that account and your error will go away.

If you are not able to set up the audit, talk to you networking guys and tell them what you are troubleshooting.

I am not sure, off hand, which account IIS might be using in this case. It may be the account that actually runs the service (probable?), but there may be another account involved. Even though you are using the TFS account, which may well be admin, it is delegating work to IIS for the deploy.

Good luck!

Comment: I found this article on auditing...
http://www.gregthatcher.com/Papers/IT/audit.aspx

Comment: No luck with that though
No failed access attempts appearing in the log

Comment: Is auditing on with the machine in question. You have to make sure it is set to have a failure audit.